# ggplot2 always have a left padding despite removing all grid lines and expanding the plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've tried several methods from other post however I can't seem to expand the grid to fill the entire x-axis with zero space.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = type, y = as.factor(pid), fill = value)) +
  geom_tile(color = "white") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank()
  ) +
  ylab("") + 
  xlab("") + 
  theme( legend.key = element_blank(), legend.position = "none",
         axis.text.y = element_blank(),
         axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, size= 11 , hjust=1 ),
         axis.title.x = element_text(size=12),
         axis.title.y     = element_text(size=15), 
         legend.text      =element_text(size=12),
         plot.title = element_text(size = 15, face = "bold"),
         plot.margin = unit(c(0, 0, 0, 0), "pt"),
         axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
         axis.line.y = element_blank()
  ) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0) ) +  # Remove x-axis padding
  scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0, 0))  # Remove y-axis padding
```

below is a screen shot with a red arrow indicating the white space. thanks in advance.

reproducible data:

```
df=structure(list(pid = structure(10:1, levels = c("10", "9", "8", 
"7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2", "1"), class = "factor"), type = c("drug", 
"drug", "drug", "drug", "drug", "drug", "drug", "drug", "drug", 
"drug"), value = c("SD", "PD", "PD", "SD", "PR", "PD", "PR", 
"PR", "CR", "CR")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ylab(NULL)` or `labs(y=NULL)` should do it. It seems that axis.text.y = element_blank removes the text of the axis label (which you've set as `""` which is effectively text that is zero characters wide but one character tall) without removing the space it would occupy.

btw, same goes for the x axis which has space for the axis title which is blank.

edit: we can also add `axis.ticks.length = unit(0, "pt"), axis.ticks.length.x = NULL` to remove the space that `theme_minimal()` sets aside for axis ticks, or alternatively start from `theme_void()` and only add the components which are desired.

[image]

FYI, to see what code is in `theme_void()`, in the RStudio IDE we can command-click it to see the function code:

```
function (base_size = 11, base_family = "", base_line_size = base_size/22,    base_rect_size = base_size/22)  {   half_line <- base_size/2   t <- theme(line = element_blank(), rect = element_blank(), 
    text = element_text(family = base_family, face = "plain", 
      colour = "black", size = base_size, lineheight = 0.9, 
      hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5, angle = 0, margin = margin(), 
      debug = FALSE), axis.text = element_blank(), axis.title = element_blank(), 
    axis.ticks.length = unit(0, "pt"), axis.ticks.length.x = NULL, 
    axis.ticks.length.x.top = NULL, axis.ticks.length.x.bottom = NULL, 
    axis.ticks.length.y = NULL, axis.ticks.length.y.left = NULL, 
    axis.ticks.length.y.right = NULL, legend.box = NULL, 
    legend.key.size = unit(1.2, "lines"), legend.position = "right", 
    legend.text = element_text(size = rel(0.8)), legend.title = element_text(hjust = 0), 
    strip.clip = "inherit", strip.text = element_text(size = rel(0.8)), 
    strip.switch.pad.grid = unit(half_line/2, "pt"), strip.switch.pad.wrap = unit(half_line/2, 
      "pt"), panel.ontop = FALSE, panel.spacing = unit(half_line, 
      "pt"), plot.margin = unit(c(0, 0, 0, 0), "lines"), 
    plot.title = element_text(size = rel(1.2), hjust = 0, 
      vjust = 1, margin = margin(t = half_line)), plot.title.position = "panel", 
    plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0, vjust = 1, margin = margin(t = half_line)), 
    plot.caption = element_text(size = rel(0.8), hjust = 1, 
      vjust = 1, margin = margin(t = half_line)), plot.caption.position = "panel", 
    plot.tag = element_text(size = rel(1.2), hjust = 0.5, 
      vjust = 0.5), plot.tag.position = "topleft", complete = TRUE)   ggplot_global$theme_all_null %+replace% t }
```

Comment: thanks! it looks much better now; there is still a very white sliver, strange how the right side goes all the way but the left there is still a tiny gap, albeit much smaller now that I i set both lab to NULL as you suggested.  link to new image: https://i.imgur.com/2fNYKrn.png

Comment: For similar reasons as for the text, you'd need to add `axis.ticks.length = unit(0, "pt"), axis.ticks.length.x = NULL` so that no space is set aside for the blank axis ticks -- that's one of the attributes in `theme_void()` which distinguish it from the others, and which might make it a simpler starting point.